# show currency images (flags) in open cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart

is there any way to add currency images (flags) in place of currency text in open cart in header.

i am trying to sort this out from many days but not happening.

and also i want to have jaquery or ajax drop down to select currencies like in the image bellow

[image]

of any open cart extension for that?
Thanks

Comment: I think you should do it manually by editing template files and CSS. Or use OC theme witch such features.

Answer (score 0):

That used to be how opencart looked in 1.4.X - in 1.5 this has changed to just flags in the default theme. Most themes will actually take care of this in their own way since they can't guarantee a person will have a specific module enabled and visible on their cart. As far as I know there is no mod for this, but you can search the extension store to see